# don't understand this use of assert in this Class

Tags: c++11

this is the header definition.

```
   #ifndef ENTITY_H
#define ENTITY_H
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
//  Name:   BaseGameEntity.h
//
//  Desc:   Base class for a game object
//
//  Author: Mat Buckland 2002 (fup@ai-junkie.com)
//
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <string>

#include "messaging/Telegram.h"


class BaseGameEntity
{

private:

  //every entity must have a unique identifying number
  int          m_ID;


  static int  m_iNextValidID;

  void SetID(int val);

public:

  BaseGameEntity(int id)
  {
    SetID(id);
  }

  virtual ~BaseGameEntity(){}

  //all entities must implement an update function
  virtual void  Update()=0;

  //all entities can communicate using messages. They are sent
  //using the MessageDispatcher singleton class
  virtual bool  HandleMessage(const Telegram& msg)=0;

  int           ID()const{return m_ID;}  
};

#endif

/////////////// here begins the cpp definition

#include "BaseGameEntity.h"
#include <cassert>


int BaseGameEntity::m_iNextValidID = 0;


void BaseGameEntity::SetID(int val)
{
  //make sure the val is equal to or greater than the next available ID
  assert ( (val >= m_iNextValidID) && "<BaseGameEntity::SetID>: invalid ID");

  m_ID = val;

  m_iNextValidID = m_ID + 1;
}
```

What Does assert statement check for in this case? And why the use of ":" after SetID in assert statement?  I know the use of : to initialise elements via a constructor? But this usage is new to me.

Comment: I don't see the point of the assert. It will always succeed.

Comment: Please don't ask five unrelated questions in one.

Comment: Are you sure you've copied the code correctly?  There are many small mistakes such as confusing `ID` and `m_ID`.  Also, I cannot see any `:?`.

Comment: Also, why do your refer to this as a class "template?" I don't see any use of templates here. Aside from the other syntax errors, perhaps you could post an actual piece of code that would compile?

Comment: You can't have 2 class members with the same name. Have you even tried to compile this? If you have a question about something you've seen in real code, show us the real code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a *common* trick when using `assert` macro from `<cassert>`. The macro fails if its argument  evaluates to **false**, then the program exits without any readable diagnostic message (usually just a line number, file and **stringified condition** of the `assert()`).

That is, to improve the diagnostic message, one can *hack* the boolean expression by adding a string literal that will be printed out together with the condition:

```
assert((val >= m_iNextValidID) && "<BaseGameEntity::SetID>: invalid ID");
//                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The string literal always evaluates to boolean `true` (because it is *a pointer*), hence, it makes no impact to the condition itself. However, when the first operand of `&&` condition fails, then the entire condtion is not satisfied (due to its logic) and assert ends the program, printing out:

```
Assertion failed: (val >= m_iNextValidID) && "<BaseGameEntity::SetID>: invalid ID"
```

Then, seeing this message, one can know that the provided ID for `SetID` method was not valid.